# ASP.NET Core MVC adds extra <input> only when wrapped in form, cannot exclude

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Edit: To clarify, using the HtmlHelpers `Checkbox` and `CheckboxFor` automatically render an extra input. Previously in .Net framework projects, we've used a custom Html Helper to write a single `<input type=checkbox`, named something like `CheckboxSimpleFor` and it's worked well. In a .Net core project, the same process no longer works. Using any Html helpers to render a single checkbox will still get two - for example, if we use a `@Html.CheckboxSimpleFor`, it will now render just the single checkbox, but now, right before the `</form>` closing tag, it will add however many duplicate checkboxes. This is not behavior we've seen in the past. It appears that something in the pipeline detects based on the model and will inject these right before closing the form.

C# & ASP.NET Core MVC seems to add an extra hidden input element when rendering input types of checkbox. In .NET, you could work around this by customizing an HTML Helper that would render only only input tag.

In ASP.NET Core, if the `@Html.Checkbox` occurs within a `<form>` element, it auto-appends an extra field of the same name that you cannot remove.

For example, this renders one input tag for `CrossCompanyJobRangeActive`:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CrossCompanyJobRangeId)
<div class="row">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CrossCompanyJobRangeActive)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.CrossCompanyJobRangeActive)
</div>
```

This renders two, with the second as false:

```
<form>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CrossCompanyJobRangeId)
    <div class="row">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CrossCompanyJobRangeActive)
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.CrossCompanyJobRangeActive)
    </div>
</form>
```

I've tried using `tags` instead of `CheckboxFor` and it does the same thing. I've tried using a custom Html writer, but any instance of `@Html` seems to get picked up by the form renderer and it will append the extra field at the end. This breaks serializing the form to Javascript. Is there any way at all to use either tags and helpers in a form for checkboxes and to keep the pipeline from inserting extra fields?

Custom Html helpers do not help when wrapped in a `form` element. For example, something like

```
content = htmlHelper.CheckBox(name, isChecked.Value, htmlAttributes);
checkBox = htmlHelper.ToHtmlString(content);
```

as an Html helper will render two `<input type=checkbox` when outside a `form`, which you can strip out, but only one when inside a `form`, which you can't strip out, and then the final rendered html has it anyways.

Comment: Do you get the same behaviour when using `Html.BeginForm`?

Comment: Yes, using `BeginForm` was the first attempt - I've been modifying each component individually, but it seems to "know" when it's in a form and will add the extra `input type=checkbox` at the end if necessary. It's a pipeline I can't follow because even using custom html rendering, `htmlHelper.Checkbox` will either render one or two depending on the path, but it will still add a second in final rendering.

Comment: Not really sure what you mean, can you show the HTML that is generated? Also, you didn#t say, but I presume `CrossCompanyJobRangeActive` is a bool property?

Comment: @DavidG I've put together a long pastebin here: https://pastebin.com/zT2Beesm It shows that it generates the extra `input` using `CheckBoxFor` which is expected in MVC, but using a custom Html helper, it still adds an extra `CheckBoxFor` at the end of the form, no matter what I try.

Comment: Oh I see, that is expected, note the second one is hidden. See the duplicate for the explanation why!

Comment: Correct, the second one is auto added and I'm familiar with it. The question linked as a duplicate is not the same. Using a custom Html helper (which we've used to resolve this in .net framework projects) still renders an extra input in .net core. In the linked pastebin, there is a custom Html helper to render a single input tag. This no longer works in .net core, it seems if the pipeline notices an checkbox with the same name as a model property, it will now add one at the end of the form automatically, no matter what.